# How to use aliases in query for making conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, alias

I have `user` table like as follows

```
user_id    name    gender    age
--------------------------------
1          AAA      Male      45
2          BBB      Female    22
3          CCC      Male      47
.................................
..............................
```

I want to get total no of users and total no of male users ans percent for male and female users

```
select count(*) as total , SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Male',1,0)) as totalMale ,
   SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Female',1,0)) as totalFemale , totalMale/total *100 ,
   totalFeMale/total *100 from user;
```

This query is not working when using aliases to calculate male and female percent.
I am getting the error like  `unknown columns..........`

```
select count(*) as total , SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Male',1,0)) as totalMale ,
SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Female',1,0)) as totalFemale , SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Male',1,0))/count(*) *100 ,SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Female',1,0))/count(*) *100 from user;
```

But this is working.

But is this i used `SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Female',1,0))` 2 times.I think it will degrade the performance.

Can't i use aliases in my situation ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is just fine. You can't use an alias at a select level. Your only option would be to have a derived table but that will indeed degrade performance.

Just one thing to improve the query performance would be to change the Gender column into just a boolean or char column.

Tip: All non-null boolean comparisons in MySQL resolve to 1 (true) and 0 (false), so you could simplify your query this way:

```
select
    count(*) total,
    SUM(gender = 'Male') totalMale,
    SUM(gender = 'Female') totalFemale,
    SUM(gender = 'Male') / count(*) * 100 percentageMale,
    SUM(gender = 'Female') / count(*) * 100 percentageFemale
from user
```

Comment: But here i have other conditions with gender

Comment: can i write SUM(gender = 'Male' and condition2 and conditiond3)  like this?

Comment: Same rule applies. `COND1 and COND2 and COND3` will always return true or false (for non-null operands)

Comment: will it improve performance ? if i write this instead of  SUM(IF(gender = 'Male',1,0))

Comment: you means in database changing column datatype ?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned the only performance issue is using char/varchar field for the sex which will have (most likely) only 2 values. The rest is just a tip that makes the query more readable but has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: But actually in my database i have boolean only.To explain clearly i posted like that

Answer (score 0):

Add inner query like this.

```
Select t1.total ,
t1.totalMale/total *100 ,
t1.totalFeMale/t1.total *100  
from 
(select 
count(user_id) as total , 
SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Male',1,0)) as totalMale ,
SUM(IF(v.gender = 'Female',1,0)) as totalFemale 
from user)t1;
```

Comment: As per my knowledge there is no much difference in  performance between them.